# Google Map didn't work after following instructions from Google Map site

Tags: html, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I followed the instructions from https://developers.google.com/maps/tutorials/fundamentals/adding-a-google-map

When I run it at Netbeans 8.0.2, only the gray div showed up, no map was shown.

This is my code:

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Practicing Google Maps</title>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css" />
    <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js">
        function initialize() {

            // The Map object constructor takes two arguments:

            /* 
             * A reference to the div that the map will be loaded into. We use
             * the JavaScript getElementById function to obtain this:
             */
            var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

            /* 
             * Options for the map, such as the center, zoom level, and the map type.
             * There are many more options that can be set, but these three are required:
             */
            var mapOptions = {
                center: new.google.maps.LatLng(44.5403. -78.5463),
                zoom: 8,
                mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
            }

            var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas);
        }

        /*
         * Add an event listener to the window object that will call the initialize function
         * once the page has loaded. Calling initialize before the page has finished loading
         * will cause problems, since the div it's looking for may not have been created
         * yet; this function waits until the HTML elements on the page have been created
         * before calling initialize.
         */
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="map-canvas">

    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

What did I miss? I even comment Google's instructions so I will not miss a thing but still, Google Map didn't show up.

Thank you.

Comment: What is in stylesheet.css?

Comment: You need to give the div `map-canvas` some dimensions

Comment: I have dimensions on my div, I just forgot to mention it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You appear to be missing the closing `</script>` after loading the Google maps library.  And then an opening `<script>` tag for your code.  You also have a few typos, corrected below:

`center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),`

You've also left out `mapOptions` when initializing the map:

`var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);`

And finally, your div should have some dimensions.

Working code below:

```js
function initialize() {

  var mapCanvas = document.getElementById('map-canvas');

  var mapOptions = {
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(44.5403, -78.5463),
    zoom: 8,
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
  }

  var map = new google.maps.Map(mapCanvas, mapOptions);
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

```html
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js"></script>
<div style="height:200px; width:200px" id="map-canvas">
```

Answer (score 0):

Try adding a dimension to your map-canvas div. This usually works.

`<div id="map-canvas" style="width:100%; height:100%;"></div>`